# Bellman-Ford algorithm undirected graph with destination node

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Suppose we have a undirected graph with n vertices.If we wanted to find the shortest path from the starting vertex to any vertex we would have to apply the Bellman-Ford algorithm for n-1 iterations.
However if there was a destination vertex , wouldnt the number of iterations be reduced by 1 to have in total (n-2) iterations?

Comment: Why would it? Is the destination vertex treated specially in any way?

Comment: Since we want to find the shortest route to the destination vertex we dont need to iterate for the destination vertex.

Comment: Yes, it seems the last iteration can be reduced to just the destination vertex,